# The limit of partial sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

how can I find sum of this series

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k-1}{k^{2}}$=?

Comment: This series is  divergent,

Comment: @math See my answer for a comparison to the harmonic series.

Comment: @math: math110 just did...

Comment: @AlexR,Yes, I have edit.

Answer (score 3):

Since the individual terms are positive,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k^2} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k^2} \geq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k}{k^2} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1k = \infty$$